# Datepicker DialogFragment mono for android

Tags: c#, android, .net, mono, xamarin.android

I'm developing this application that has a DatePicker in one of the fragments. To have a Diolog I've learned that you must use custom built DialogFragments, that was quite easy when making a AlertDialog or a ProgressDialog but when it comes to a DatePickerDialog I got stuck.

Is there anyone out there who can explain how to do this or have some code examples for a DatePicker DialogFragment? Somehow this DatePickerFragment should be able to sent the selected date to the Fragment who started it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
public class MyDateTimeDialogFragment : DialogFragment
{
    public event EventHandler DateChanged;
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    private readonly int _year;
    private readonly int _day;
    private readonly int _month;

    public MyDateTimeDialogFragment(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        _year = year;
        _month = month;
        _day = day;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity, CallBack, _year, _month, _day);
        return dialog;
    }

    private void CallBack(object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs dateSetEventArgs)
    {
        Date = dateSetEventArgs.Date;
        if (DateChanged != null)
            DateChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You could expand it a bit with creating your own `EventArgs` and `EventHandler` to pass along the `DateTime` in the `DateChanged` event.